# Prevent direct use of GPU in single-node slurm setup

Tags: permissions, slurm

**Scenario:** I have installed slurm in a single Ubuntu machine. Users may login into this machine to do some GPU and non-GPU tasks.

**Goal:** I want to prevent those users from directly using the GPUs. Only jobs started with slurm should be able to use the GPUs.

**What I've done:** To prevent direct use of the GPUs, I've changed the owner of  */dev/nvidiaN* (`chown root.gpu /dev/nvidia*`), now only users within group `gpu` can use them. That works. The problem is: slurm jobs, of course, run as the same user they are started with, so these submitted jobs cannot use any GPUs either.

Is any way to accomplish this goal? I thought about using mirror users (`user` -> `user-slurm` within group `gpu` but no login), sudo with some `sbatch --uid=UID --guid=GID ...` white-listed commands, but this seems awfully convoluted.

Comment: I would think of creating another virtual Ubuntu machine that would serve as a headnode and move the users to this machine. Employ the normal slurm PAM plugin to allow access to the original machine from the virtual headnode only via SLURM.

Comment: I think you could restrict `sshd` in a `cgroup` that denies access to `/dev/nvidia*` through systemd's `.service` file.

Comment: I am in the exact same situation... @tokland what did you end up doing?

Comment: I imagine one possibility is to [setgid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on srun/sbatch so that it automatically runs with a gpu-enabled group id.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. In my lab, we want to setup [a local SLURM](https://blog.llandsmeer.com/tech/2020/03/02/slurm-single-instance.html) in a single-node GPU. We want a simple solution so that only SLURM can use the GPU. This seems to be a harder proposition than it would seem at first.

The solution I am going with is (from time to time) to kill any process using the GPU that has not been launched through SLURM. This can be done by a relatively simple Python script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Kills all processes using /dev/nvidia* that have not
# been initiated by SLURM.

import os, subprocess, psutil, syslog

# get all nvidia devices
devs = []
i = 0
while os.path.exists(f'/dev/nvidia{i}'):
    devs.append(f'/dev/nvidia{i}')
    i += 1

# get all processes using any of those devices
out = subprocess.check_output(['lsof', '-t'] + devs)

# kill processes whose parent is not SLURM (slurmstepd)
for pid in out.split():
    p = process = psutil.Process(int(pid))
    has_slurm_parent = False
    while p := p.parent():
        if p.name() == 'slurmstepd':
            has_slurm_parent = True
            break
    if not has_slurm_parent:
        syslog.syslog(f'Killing process {pid} {process.name()} ({process.username()}) - cannot use GPU outside of SLURM')
        process.kill()
```

Then, just add this to cron (`sudo crontab -e`) to run every 5 minutes or so:

```
*/5 * * * * python3 /path/to/script.py
```

---

Furthermore, since this script is only a last-resort defense, it is also a good idea to prevent this from being necessary by disabling the cuda visible devices at `/etc/environment`:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
```

We can also lock this variable for the case of bash users (`/etc/profile.d/xxxx.sh`) together with a nice welcome message:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
readonly CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
echo "Use srun or sbatch to access the GPU."
```

Comment: Regarding CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES... How do you give slurm user access to the GPU? It is also affected by the variable

Comment: @Rockcat: `readonly` only affects variables defined inside bash, it does not affect environment variables assigned to the process through exec or other means (which is why we also need the script above). At least for SLURM 19.05.5, I can assure you this is not a problem.

Comment: Can confirm that is working. Also It could be a good idea to export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="Use srun or sbatch to access the GPU." to give a clue of why that variable is there.

Comment: On our machine, there are some background housekeeping processes on the GPUs which (I believe) would be killed by this script. This can be prevented by adding arguments like `-u^root -u^nvidia-persistenced` to the `lsof` call, which filters out jobs which are owned by `root` and `nvidia-persistenced` (check if you have other background process owners on your machine).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a BASH version of the python script proposed by Ricardo Magalhães Cruz

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for pid in $( /usr/bin/lsof -t /dev/nvidia* )
do 
  grep -q -e "slurmd.service" -e "nvidia.*service" /proc/$pid/cgroup && continue
  echo "Killing process $pid from user $(stat -c "%U" /proc/$pid/ ) - cannot use GPU outside of SLURM"
  kill -9 $pid 
done
```

The grep line will avoid to kill processes executed by slurm, of the nvidia-fabricmanager and nvidia-fabricmanager processes.

As in the original solution, you need to instruct cron to run every 5 minutes, by executing the crontab editor (`sudo crontab -e`) and adding the line:

*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh

Comment: "slurmd.service" should be replaced with "slurmstepd.scope" for groups v2.